# How to configure Nightwatch's new HTML reporter to save each result individually?

Tags: javascript, typescript, configuration, nightwatch.js

I'm currently struggling with the new Nightwatch inbuild reporter configuration and am finally able to open the result in the browser after the test run (via *--open* in CLI), but I want to save each report's result that I run.

We used ***nightwatch-html-reporter*** before and there was a ***uniqueFilename*** property for it.

How could I do this with the new Nightwatch inbuild reporter?

Here is the **`nigthwatch.conf.js`** that I currently use:

```
const chrome = require('chromedriver')
const firefox = require('geckodriver')
const edge = require('edgedriver')

module.exports = {
    src_folders: ["./dist/tests"],
    globals_path: "./dist/utils/Globals.js",
    asyncHookTimeout: 10000,
    end_session_on_fail: false,
    skip_testcases_on_fail: false,
    abortOnAssertionFailure: false,
    waitForConditionPollInterval: 200,
    waitForConditionTimeout: 5000,
    retryAssertionTimeout: 5000,
    disable_colors: true,
    output_folder: "./tests_output/reports",
    screenshots: {
        enabled: true,
        path: "./tests_output/screenshots",
        on_failure: true,
        on_error: true
    },
    test_settings: {
        chrome: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: "chrome",
                "goog:chromeOptions": {
                    "args": [
                        // "-headless",
                        "start-maximized"
                    ]
                }
            },
            webdriver: {
                start_process: true,
                port: 9515,
                server_path: chrome.path
            }
        },
        firefox: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: "firefox",
                "moz:firefoxOptions": {
                    "args": [
                        //"-headless",
                        "--width=1920",
                        "--height=1080"
                    ]
                }
            },
            webdriver: {
                start_process: true,
                port: 9516,
                server_path: firefox.path
            }
        },
        edge: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: "MicrosoftEdge",
                "moz:firefoxOptions": {
                    "args": [
                        //"-headless",
                        "--width=1920",
                        // "--height=1080"
                    ]
                }
            },
            webdriver: {
                start_process: true,
                port: 9517,
                server_path: edge.path
            }
        }
    },
}
```

**`Dependencies`**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/nightwatch": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "chromedriver": "^102.0.0",
    "edgedriver": "^4.17134.1",
    "geckodriver": "^3.0.2",
    "nightwatch": "^2.3.0",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nightwatch Team has an active PR on this issue: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/pull/3309